# How do I select a directory on Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

We are trying to make it possible for users to select entire folders to upload them to our back end. This is no problem on Android and iOS, where I can use `getDirectoryPath()` from [`FilePicker`](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), and then get all the files using `Directory(path).listSync(recursive: true)`.

The issue is that this isn't available on web, and while i can exchange `dart:io` for `universal_io`, that doesn't help with `getDirectoryPath()`.

Is there any other approach that I can use here? The end goal is to upload the selected folder to Google Cloud Storage, so one Idea that I have is to bypass Flutter entirely, but I haven't figured out a way to do that yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) and [showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker), which would be the way to go, but it is not supported by all browsers.

One option would be to allow a user to pick multiple files and upload bytes. Not the same thing, but in some cases would be sufficient. Something like this:

```
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false);

if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
  final fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  final fileName = result.files.first.name;
  
  // TODO upload file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **JavaScript library**: You can use a JavaScript library such as `file-uploader` or `dropzone.js` to handle file uploads in your web application. These libraries provide a file explorer interface for the user to select and upload files, and can be integrated with Flutter using `dart:js` and `package:js`